# Are aws api gateway urls permanently unique

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

I am wondering if I write a cron job to send data to AWS api gateway using their provided public url. Then, if I delete my API gateway, will someone else be able to register the same endpoint url either by choice or by luck and be able to receive my data?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

The short answer is - **no**.

---

A bit longer answer is that the publicly accessible API URL associated with your API Gateway is unique and if you delete it, it will no longer be valid or reachable.

This means that anyone trying to register the same endpoint URL, either intentionally or by chance, will not be able to receive the data that you were sending bacuase the `api-id` generation is controlled by AWS, not the user.

> api-id is generated by API Gateway, region (AWS Region) is specified by you when creating the API, and stage is specified by you when deploying the API.

What's more when you delete your API, the endpoint URL becomes released and unavailable for registration by anyone else. AWS ensures that the URL is no longer associated with your API Gateway or any other services.

Additionally, what you might consider is setting up a custom domain for your API's host name.

Read more on AWS API Gateway custom URL [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html).

Comment: Does aws have any documentation stating that released urls are unavailable for registration?